# Cron that runs on first Sunday after the first Friday of the month has passed

Tags: jenkins, cron

We work on a product whose software development team applies patch on every 1st Friday of the month. We have written some tests that we run on the Sunday after the patch is applied. So to automate the same on Jenkins, we would need a cron that runs on 1st Sunday after the 1st Friday of the month has passed.

Right now we just update our Jenkins each month considering dates, but can we automate this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naively, one would suppose that `0 3 1-7 * fri` would be "3am on the Friday that falls inside the first week of each month", and then we could use the similar logic to construct `0 3 3-9 * sun`, for the Sunday that follows two days after such a Friday.

Unfortunately, this does not work, because day of week and day of month are taken as a [disjunction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34357126/why-crontab-uses-or-when-both-day-of-month-and-day-of-week-specified) by the cron specification; which means, the above would trigger not on the Sunday following the first Friday in a month, but on *every* Sunday, *and also every day* from 3rd to 9th.

Due to this twist in cron spec, what you ask is not possible by cron alone. The easiest way to untangle this is to separate the two requirements, ask the cron to track one of them, and manually test the other: either use `0 3 3-9 * *` and then manually test in your script whether the day is Sunday and exit without performing your task if it is not, or use `0 3 * * sun` and manually make sure the date is between 3rd and 9th.

Comment: Thanks @Amadan. I think 0 3 3-9 * 7 would work for what I want.

Comment: No, it wouldn't (and I explained why, and the linked answer goes into more detail). It would be great if it did, but...

Comment: Yep. Got it completely now @Amadan. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Amadan, Sorry to bug you again. But I have kept 0 3 3-9 * 7 on my Jenkins and it states next run to be Sunday 5th Feb 2023. But as per cron and the link you shared, it should have run from 3 through 9 and on Sundays. Does Jenkins add some more functionality to its cron in that case?\

Comment: I must say I do not know; I assumed it uses the standard `cron` syntax. Apparently it does not (it adds the `H` specifier, for one thing); if it also changes how specifying both day of month and day of week works, it's both good (yay for options) and bad (it doesn't stick to spec, and also doesn't seem to document it - or at least I have not been able to find it).