# Python - Crontab run every second friday of each month

Tags: python, cron

I am using Python to schedule a Looker API job to run every second Friday of each month. Looker suggested using the crontabguru to check the code. I tried this code but it didn't work: `00 16 8-14 * */5` despite the crontab showed `At 16:00 on every day-of-month from 8 through 14 if it's on every 5th day-of-week`
https://crontab.guru/#00_16_8-14_*_*/5

I found this post but I couldn't replicate it for Python: [How to schedule to run first Sunday of every month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3241086/how-to-schedule-to-run-first-sunday-of-every-month)

Thanks guys

Comment: Do you understand the logic in the post to which you've linked? It runs the cronjob *every* sunday, but includes some shell logic to check if the day of the month is < 7. You could do something similar, although the logic for "is this the second friday" is going to be tricker than "is this the first friday".

Comment: `crontab` doesn't have method for `"second friday"` and you will have to check it on your own in code

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I understand the logic in the post. But I am new to Python so I don't know 
(1) how to add this shell logic to a Python code like create_simple_schedule(123, 234, "testing", "csv", "abc@abc.com", "email", "Hi Looker User!", "00 16 8-14 * */5") - the last part is the crontab code.
(2) how to change the logic to run it every second Friday

Comment: run it every friday and inside script check if it second friday - day 8-14. OR run in days `8-14` and inside script check if it is friday.

Comment: What happens when you use `00 16 8-14 * */5`? Does the Looker API not accept the schedule, or does the job run at the wrong times?