# How to run a Kubernetes Cron Job every first sunday of month?

Tags: kubernetes, cron

At the beginning, I used `@monthly` for the `.spec.schedule` field and it was working but I didn't like the job to be running every first of month at midnight.

I'd prefer it to be running every first Sunday of the month at 1pm.

So I tried the next one, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73826599/8439435):

```
0 13 1-7 * */7
```

But the job has been executed last Sunday (which wasn't the first of the month), so I think something's wrong.

I saw it would be possible using the `#` character:

```
0 13 * * SUN#1
```

But it produces following error when upgrading the cron job:

```
Invalid value: "0 13 * * SUN#1": failed to parse int from SUN#1: strconv.Atoi: parsing "SUN#1": invalid syntax
```

Does someone has found something to make it work (maybe for another day of the week) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by @vonc, there's no built-in support by Kubernetes' CronJob for this kind of requirement.

So I used `0 13 * * SUN` in order to run the job every Sundays and then, in the beginning of my script, I check the date and exit if above 7.

Here's an example in javascript:

```js
export const main = () => {
  // Exit when script is not run on the first Sunday of month
  if (new Date().getDate() > 7) {
    return;
  }
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To schedule a Kubernetes CronJob to run every first Sunday of the month at 1pm, you need to use a specific Cron expression. The expression you tried (`0 13 * * SUN#1`) is the correct format for certain Cron implementations, but Kubernetes does not support the [`#` character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#Non-standard_characters) in [its CronJob scheduling syntax](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/#writing-a-cronjob-spec).

Instead, you can use a combination of day-of-month and day-of-week fields:

```
0 13 1-7 * 0
```

That expression would be using:

- `0 13`: At 13:00 (or 1 pm).
- `1-7`: On days 1 through 7 of the months.
- `*`: Every month.
- `0`: Only if it is Sunday.

But this expression might still trigger on a Sunday that falls on the 2nd to 7th day of the month, if the first day of the month is not a Sunday.
To prevent this, you would need to implement additional logic outside the Cron expression: Kubernetes' CronJob does not have built-in support for this specific scheduling requirement.

One approach could be to run the job every day from the 1st to the 7th, and include a check at the start of your job script to exit if it is not the first Sunday. That logic could be implemented in the script that your CronJob runs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I came up with same conclusion so I'll write my answer to show how I've done it. Sad to see there's no built-in support for this kind of thing on Kubernetes. Do you that's something that could be added to K8s Github issues?

Comment: @Benbb96 Not sure: this syntax comes from the [2017 PR 41901](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/41901), and has not changed since. It was [discussed here](https://www.reddit.com/r/kubernetes/comments/g9bm3g/cronjob_scheduling_hashed_offset/).